# Problema con sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite3, bundler, gemfile

Despues de crear un proyecto de pruebas con ruby on rails y arrancar el servidor estoy intentando conectarme a la base de datos de sqlite3 que es la gema que viene por defecto

Archivo Gemfile (parte correspondiente a la gema de sqlite3)

```
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4"
```

Cuando ejecuto el comando `rails dbconsole` me sale el siguiente error:
Couldn't find database client: sqlite3.exe. Check your $PATH and try again.

Sin embargo sqlite lo tengo instalado y agregado al PATH, puedo ejecutarlo usando el powershell o el simbolo de sistema y desde cualquier lugar.

Comment: ¿Sigue ocurriendo el error después de reiniciar Windows?

Comment: @Warren ya arregle el error o mejor dicho me di cuenta de mi fallo. Tenia todo bien configurado pero estaba ejecutando el comando desde la terminal de visual studio code y esta era la de gitbash, solo fue cambiar de terminal a la de powershell